# Problem with my homework: boolean expression

Tags: c++, boolean, expression

I'm very new in programming and I need some help to solve this with a boolean expression:

> Check if the value of variable p is in the range of -100 to 100
>   (including limits), but not in the range of -10 to 10

Here is what I did:

```
int main (){
int p = 10;
bool comparacion =  ((p >= -100) && (p <= 100)) && ((p !>= -10) && (p !<= 10))
cout<< comparacion;
```

The result was supposed to be 0 since p is in the range of -10 to 10 but I get this compilation error:

```
[Error] expected ')' before '!' token
```

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but you don’t need any of those parentheses in the logical expression. Read about operator precedence.

Comment: There should be a semicolon at the end of the declaration

Comment: Off-topic: Checking a value being inside of an interval, I consider `if(lower <= value && value <= upper)` easier to read, it ressembles closer what we would write in mathematics as *lower <= value <= upper*...

Comment: @PeteBecker Actually, to solve task given (solely with &&), we'd need *one* pair of parentheses, as we'd need to negate one of the &&...

Comment: @Aconcagua — I don’t see a requirement to use only `&&`.

Comment: @PeteBecker And I didn't mean so either. Actually, I consider your answer including || the best of all given so far. But *if* you use && only, *then* you need one pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s much simpler if you look at it a bit differently:

```
 bool comparacion = p >= -100 && p < -10 || p > 10 && p <= 100;
```

Answer (score 4):

`!>=` and `!<=` are not valid operators. The inverse of `>=` is `<`, and the inverse of `<=` is `>`.

```
bool comparacion =  ((p >= -100) && (p <= 100)) && ((p < -10) && (p > 10))
```

Comment: @Aconcagua It solves the problem in the post; it's not my job to do his homework for him!

Comment: Fixes the operators, but not the expression itself, as a value cannot be at the same time < -10 *and* > 10 (contradiction)...

Comment: [@#$+%*!], too late for editing my comment... It's fine not to show the final solution, but I'd consider at least mentioning that the so far fixed expression still doesn't do what it was intended for as better than letting user blindly fall into the next trap.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do that :

```
bool comparacion =  ((p >= -100) && (p <= 100)) && (!((p >= -10) && (p <= 10)))
cout<< comparacion;
```

Comment: Correct? Relative... Technically, yes, but this *flood* of (surplus!) parentheses makes the expression hard to read...